# Структура данных, в которой можно быстро читать и удалять элементы из середины

Tags: python, структуры-данных

Я желаю найти индексируемую структуру данных для которой будут быстро выполняться следующие операции для произвольного индекса `i`:

- Удаление: `del struct_obj[i]`
- Изменение: `struct_obj[i] = value`
- Чтение: `var = struct_obj[i]`

То есть эта структура по своему "интерфейсу" должна примерно соответствовать структуре `list` из питона, но при этом иметь возможность быстрого удаления из середины. Взамен я готов пожертвовать скоростью чтения и изменения, а также вообще возможностью добавления новых элементов.

Пример работы структуры:

```
a = struct([3, 2, 4, 1, 5])
a[2] = 0 # a: [3, 2, 0, 1, 5]
b = a[3] # a: [3, 2, 0, 1, 5], b: 1
del a[1] # a: [3, 0, 1, 5]
a[3] = 1 # a: [3, 0, 1, 1]
```

Хранить в этой структуре я планирую 32-битные целые числа (-10^9 <= a[i] <= 10^9).

Реальной задачей, в которой такая структура может быть полезна, является классическая "считалка на выбывание": в кольце стоят N детей, пронумерованных по часовой стрелке от 1 до N. После этого из круга выходит каждый K-тый ребенок, в каком порядке они все выйдут?

Пример для задачи: N = 5, K = 3, ответ: 3, 1, 5, 2, 4.

Я знаю, что в качестве структуры мне подходит декартово дерево по неявному ключу, которое с точки зрения интерфейса взаимодействия очень похоже на динамический массив, но с логарифмической сложностью всех основных операций.

Я хочу узнать, есть ли более эффективные/простые в реализации структуры данных, отвечающие моим требованиям.

При этом я понимаю, что питон - это как раз тот язык, в котором не пишутся велосипеды на каждый чих, а используются проверенные реализации практически для всего. Поэтому я прошу вас поделиться ссылками на готовые реализации структур, о которых вы напишете в своем ответе.

Comment: вам обязательно доступ именно по индексу? Если перейти на использование словарей и доступ по ключам то сложность всех указанных операций будет `O(1)` ;)

Comment: @MaxU Мне нужно не столько получение по индексу, сколько получение следующего элемента. В этом плане мне бы больше подошел linked list, но пока я страдаю с ним, я решил спросить о наличии более интересных структур, тем более, что одну такую я знаю сам. Да и я все еще не доверяю хеш-таблицам)). Сколько статей прочитал, но все еще считаю черной магией, что можно делать все и сразу в среднем за константу.

Comment: а добавление элементов в структуру, кроме начального заполнения, должно быть реализовано?

Comment: @MaxU нет, предполагается добавление только при инициализации. Потом только удаление.

Comment: а есть ограничения по памяти?

Comment: @MaxU ну единственное ограничение - адекватность. Скажем, у меня не должен взрываться компьютер от  хранения 30000 целых чисел. В общем, примерно до N^1.5 я считаю адекватным.

Comment: Единственная идея использовать что-то вроде связного списка. Словарь где каждому элементу исходного списка соответствует два ключа: keyN с соответствующим значением  и keyN_next с именем следующего ключа в качестве значения. При удалении элемента KeyN_next нужно присвоить следующий ключ. При удалении сложность будет O(3). По памяти 2N + размер ключей

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически известно, что для операций Изменение и Чтение самая эффективная по времени реализация - это массив, для которого доступ по индексу  - О(1). Даже для словарей все на много медленнее, так как по сути словарь это сначала поиск по значению ключа и только потом само чтение или изменение. А поиск по значению ключа - это  всякие ухищрения, например, через  отдельные  индексы (как при реализации реляционных баз данных).

С другой стороны, известно, что для массивов операции Вставки и Удаления  -  наиболее медленные и трудоемкие, так как требуют смещения всех элементов после вставляемого/удаляемого, да еще и отслеживания размеров.

С третьей стороны для списков (не списков Python, а списков как Абстрактного Типа Данных) Поиск (и соответственно Изменение и Чтение) -  крайне медленные операции, однако Удаление и Вставка -  быстрые, т.е. все что надо - просто "перебросить" указатели. АТД-список можно реализовать не только через однонаправленные ссылки, но и через двунаправленные, еще больше ускорив Удаление и Вставку. Но не Поиск, Чтение, Изменение.

Любая другая реализация это в конечном итоге некий компромис между одним и вторым способом  предатавления (Например список Python -  отличный пример такого компромиса).

Неявное бинарное дерево - это отнюдь не универсальная структура, а структура для хранения упорядоченных данных. Т.е. "запаковав" данные в дерево, вы теряете некоторую информацию, например,  порядок поступления данных. Это весьма частный случай общей задачи и его можно использовать только тогда, когда между значениями хранимым элементов можно ввести отношения "больше-меньше. (а вы не сказали, что вы собираетесь работать только с упорядоченными данными, значит -  исходим из общего случая).

Все сказанное приводит к мысли, что нет и быть не может структуры для представления, изменения и доступа для  универсальных данных. Поэтому в курсах, в которых рассматриваются  структуры обычно очень усилино подчеркивается, что выбор структуры может быть осуществлен только в жесткой привязке к семантике предметной области и с учетом (вернее -  взаимоучетом) алгоритмов дальнейшей обработки.

Что касается "готовых реализаций" -  то они есть, хотя и не очень распространены, с моей точки зрения именно потому, что часто проще для конкретной, своей задачи написать реализацию самому, чем разбираться в чужом коде, написанным часто с академическими целями.

Тем не менее - если очень надо, попробуйте поискать вот тут, может что-то и попойдет:

https://treelib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://gist.github.com/irachex/3922705

http://python.algorithmexamples.com/web/data_structures/binary_tree/treap.html

http://www.grantjenks.com/wiki/random/python_treap_implementation

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне кажется, что вы не совсем меня поняли. Я не ищу какую-то идеальную структуру, я ищу ту структуру, в которой пожертвовали скоростью чтения и возможностью добавления элементов ради скорости удаления из середины. Декартово дерево я привел в качестве примера структуры, которая меня полностью устраивает по своим характеристикам: все стандартные операции в нем выполняются за логарифм от числа элементов, что я считаю очень хорошим результатом.

Comment: И мой вопрос как раз и заключался в том, чтобы найти описание структуры, которая была бы эффективнее или проще неявного декартового дерева для решения моей задачи. Кроме этого я попросил помощи в поиске адекватной реализации, которая очевидно где-то есть, но где я ее не нашел. И готовые реализации наоборот очень распространены: мы ведь давно ушли от C именно из-за того, что там все писали свои строки. Set и Map сейчас во всех языках встроенные, потому что они слишком часто используются, чтобы каждый писал свои версии.

Comment: И спасибо за приведенные ссылки. К сожалению, я не могу прямо сейчас разобраться, что там внутри, но вечером - обязательно.

Comment: @EzikBro ---  "ищу ту структуру, в которой пожертвовали скоростью чтения и возможностью добавления элементов ради скорости удаления из середины"  тогда все намного проще. Такая структура - это Словарь. Удаление из середины - максимально быстро. А в реализации словарей в Python - еще и разумный компромисс по объему необходимой дополнительной памяти. Но я так и не понял -  если вас устраивает Декартово дерево, то данные у вас все-таки поддаются предварительному упорядочению?  Это критично важная посылка.

Comment: Удаление из середины со смещением следующих индексов. Полностью аналогичное del list_[i] для обычных питоновских листов, но работающее намного быстрее. В случае словарей: a = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3}; del a[1]; a == {0:0, 1:2, 2:3} не выполняется).

Comment: Честно говоря не понял, о чем вы. Для словаря del a[1] удаляет весь элемент (пару) -  и ключ и значение. Индекса в словаре нет по определению.  Да и выполняется оно не быстрее, чем удаление из списка по индексу.

Comment: @passant, удаление элемента словаря по ключу в среднем занимает `O(1)`, а для списка `O(n)` - [источник](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: @MaxU  -  да, вы правы. Последнюю фразу в моем предыдущем комментарии - считать недействительной :-)

Comment: Я переписал свой вопрос, постаравшись ответить на ваши вопросы. Буду благодарен, если вы посмотрите и ответите на мой новую версию вопроса. Ваши ссылки посмотрел - везде приведены реализации неупорядоченного дерева, которое не поддерживает никакого индексирования. Если я как-то это индексирование там проглядел, сильно извиняюсь.

Comment: @MaxU Посмотрел код реализации ( https://habr.com/ru/post/273045/) Действительно O(n) -  вычислительная сложность удаления элемента ПО ЗАНЧЕНИЮ (т.е. remove). И это понятно - надо сделать в среднем n/2 сравнения, что-бы найти удаляемый элемент. А вот удаление ПО ИНДЕКСУ - должно быть гораздо быстрее -  О(1) ибо сравнения нет, а есть простой переход в массиве по заданному индексу.  Понятно, что время на перемещение массива указателей тоже необходимо учитывать. Засада  еще может быть и в том, что del -  универсальная функция с кучей ненужных проверок. Надо бы код найти и посмотреть.

Comment: @ EzikBro -  в свете моего предыдущего замечания про удаление по значению и по индексу -  мне кажется, что список - наиболее подходящая для вас структура.